# How can i convert css in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i convert css in jquery.I tried but it is not working. Please help anyone.

CSS:

```
#conpanel .cont .bs{
 background-color:#fff !important;
 border: 0px solid #ccc !important;
 border-width: thin 0px 0px 0px 0px  !important;
 padding: 3px 0 1px 22px !important;
}

#conpanel .cont.bg{
border-bottom: 0px solid #99bbd4;
border-top: medium none;}
```

Jquery:

```
   $('#conpanel .cont .bs').attr('style', 'padding: 3px 0 1px 32px !important','border-width: thin 0px 0px 0px 0px  !important');   
   $('#conpanel .cont .bs').css({ 'background-color':'#fff !important','border': '0px solid #ccc !important'}); 
   $('#conpanel .cont .bs').css({'border': '0px solid #ccc !important'});

   $('#conpanel .cont .bg').css({'border-bottom': '0px solid #99bbd4','border-top': 'medium none'});
```

Answer (score 1):

just use this and it will do the trick:

```
$('.bs').css('border-bottom','0px solid #99bbd4');
```

Answer (score 0):

For the last line, your selector is wrong. I also added the first batch into one:

```
$('#conpanel .cont .bs').css({
    'background-color': '#fff !important',
    'border': '0px solid #ccc !important',
    'border-width': 'thin 0px 0px 0px 0px !important',
    'padding': '3px 0 1px 22px !important'
});    

$('#conpanel .cont.bg').css({
  'border-bottom': '0px solid #99bbd4',
  'border-top': 'medium none'
});
```

Note, I changed `#conpanel .cont.bg`.
These overrides will set inline styles, so you probably don't need the 'important', depending on the context, as they will override the rules you set already.

Comment: can u change for all?

Comment: Added the first one there, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Possible because the !important was removed, do you need it from the original rules or can they be removed?

Comment: Added `!important` back in, I'd be surprised if that didn't work.

Comment: Okay, well if you can't provide any more details I can't help any more.

Comment: css is not applying So can u use style attr? like this:$('#conpanel .cont .bs').attr('style',

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks correct. I think it could possibly be that you are using `!important` in your css file as well as trying to set it with jQuery. Try removing `!important` from the css file and see if that fixes it.

Html:

```
<div id="alter-div">
    <p>My Div</p>    
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery part:

```
$("#alter-div").css({

  "background-color": "blue",
  "border": "1px solid black",
  "border-top": "1px solid red"

});
```